# sqlite - programmatically determine primary key(s)

Tags: sqlite, schema, primary-key

I need to programatically determine what the primary key field(s) are for a given sqlite table (using sqlite api, not command line).

I can get a list of tables and a list of columns, but only see the column type using the Column_Type() function.  Need to know if a given column is the primary key (or part of the primary key if a compound key is used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [sqlite3_table_column_metadata](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/table_column_metadata.html):

> This routine returns metadata about a specific column of a specific
>   database table accessible using the database connection handle passed
>   as the first function argument.